# D3 adding element to zoomed map

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, maps

I have a map where circles (origin of people) appear when clicking on a legend.

Additionally, it is possible to zoom in, and then, circles (and country path) are transformed (using d3.behavior.zoom).

Though, if I first zoom in, and then click on the legend, circles do not appear at the right places. How can I solve this problem and append them at the right coordinates (within the zoomed map).

Any ideas? I'm sure the solution is not that difficult, but I'm stucked.

See (http://wahrendorf.de/circlemapping/world_question.html) for an example.

Thanks,

Morten

Comment: Looks like your projection is not being scaled with the rest of the map. Try scaling your projection in the `zoom` method to keep it inline with the zoom of the whole map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account `d3.event.translate` and `d3.event.scale` when you draw the circles. The easiest way to do this is to factor out your zoom function so that it may be called by the circle drawing function.

```
var translate = [0,0];
var scale = 1;
var zoom_function = function() {
    canvas.selectAll("path")
             .attr("transform","translate("+translate.join(",")+")scale("+scale+")");

    canvas.selectAll("circle.origin")
             .attr("transform","translate("+translate.join(",")+")scale("+scale+")")
             .attr("r", function(d) { return radius/scale; });
};
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1,6])
           .on("zoom",function() {
              translate = d3.event.translate;
              scale = d3.event.scale;
              zoom_function();
});

// ... The rest of the code ...

canvas.append("text")
      .text("show circles")
      .attr("x", 30 ) .attr("y", 480 )
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .on("click", function(d)  {
          /// load data with long/lat of circles
          d3.csv("./World_files/places_q.csv", function(error, origin) {
              canvas.selectAll("circle.origin").remove();
              canvas.selectAll("circle.origin")
            .data(origin)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d) {return projection([d.originlong, d.originlat])[0];})
                    .attr("cy", function(d) {return projection([d.originlong, d.originlat])[1];})
                    .attr("r", 2)
                    .style("fill", "red")
                    .style("opacity", 0.5)
                    .attr("class", "origin");
              // Call the zoom function here to fix the placement of the circles.
              zoom_function();
          });
    });
```

You will need to track the last known `d3.event.translate` and `d3.event.scale` values since they will be undefined when you are drawing the circles.